# Can I access Nautilus's bookmarks in terminal?

Tags: directory, nautilus

I have made a some bookmarks in Nautilus, i.e. shortcut links to some directories.

I would like to `cd` to a directory which has been bookmarked in Nautilus. I was wondering if that is possible?

Comment: Do you really want the bookmarks, or do you want mounted network locations?

Comment: The bookmarks point to some directories on my local file system. THere is no network involved.

Answer (score 22):

Nautilus saves its bookmarks in a file named `.gtk-bookmarks` in your home (from Ubuntu 13.04 on, it's located in `.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks`). The bookmarks are stored in clear text, one bookmark per line. With a bit of shell scripting it should be possible to parse the file and configure your shell to allow something like: `cd somebookmarkname`.

Comment: add this to your shell's startup files (bash, zsh and similar): function cdbm
    {
     cd $(grep $1 ~/.gtk-bookmarks | awk '-F//' '{print $2}')
    }

Answer (score 2):

Old thread, but in case it helps someone, the helpful comment by @SuperMagic didn't work for me in `ksh`, so instead I put this in `.kshrc`:

```
function cdbm { 
   ENTRY=$(grep "$1" $HOME/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks) 
   DIR=$(echo "$ENTRY" | sed 's|file://||g' | cut -d' ' -f1)
   cd $DIR
}
```

Comment: This also works in `bash` (`./bashrc`).

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you can access Nautilus bookmarks at `${HOME}/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks` with the format `file://${PATH}`. However, this is the wrong approach for what you are trying to do. Simply create a BASH/ZSH variable or alias for the paths in your RC file so that they are automatically loaded. If you want to write a script, write one that automatically populates your RC file with data from your bookmarks file:

```bash
$ awk -F 'file://' '{ split($2, i, "/"); print i[4] "=" "\""$2"\""; }' "${HOME}/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks" | tee -a "${HOME}/.bashrc"

$ cat "${HOME}/.bashrc"
Documents="${HOME}/Documents"
Music="${HOME}/Music"
Pictures="${HOME}/Pictures"
Videos="${HOME}/Videos"
Downloads="${HOME}/Downloads"
```